# Add file from within an external project to a local project

Tags: svn, externals

I'm using the svn:external to get projects like Nlog and Lucene.net.
They don't have a vs2008 csproj file.
I can create that one easely so I can add it to other projects.
Is it now possible to add this 2008 project file to our internal source control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this regard, SVN works folder-based. If a folder is checked out as "external" to some working copy, you cannot add anything in there to the working copy itself.